# Magento Plugin Password Policy

Tags: magento2, extensions, security, password

Is there any magento plugin that has the features below:

1. force the user changed password in every 90 days.
2. change password must required min 8 char

Comment: Are you referring to a customer or an admin user?

Comment: is about admin user

Answer (score 3):

**Password lifetime**

This is a standard feature of Magento 2 (CE + EE). In the system configuration there is a section for "security" (see "Advanced" > "Admin") where you can define the Password Lifetime in days (for example 90) and set the password change behaviour (forced or recommended).

[image]
See also: http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/stores/security-admin.html

**Password length**

The current minimum password length for admin users is [7 characters](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/6ea7d2d85cded3fa0fbcf4e7aa0dcd4edbf568a6/app/code/Magento/User/Model/UserValidationRules.php#L21).

As far as I know there is currently no extension that sets the minimum password length to 8.

Comment: have plugin for the password lifetime because my magento is not that version, so can't use?